# What's the most performant condition when dealing with multiple OR?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

Let's assume a `translation` table:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint |
| key | text |
| locale | varchar(10) |
| value | text |

with a unique index on `(key, locale)`.

I have a bulk endpoint where I want to get multiple key/locale combinations, e.g.

```json
{
  "key": "foo",
  "locales": ["a", "b", "c"]
},
{
  "key": "bar",
  "locales": ["c", "d", "e"]
},
```

I'm currently constructing a query per request item, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM translation
WHERE (key = 'foo' AND locale in ('a', 'b', 'c'))
   OR (key = 'bar' AND locale in ('c', 'd', 'e'));
```

When the request size increased (max limit of 500 items), you can imagine that's a lot of OR statements.

1. I'm wondering if this is not a good approach for query performance
2. Given that keys have a higher cardinality than locales (total of ~50), should I group the other way around to possibly reduce OR conditions (in this particular example I'd get 5 statements instead of 2), e.g.

   ```sql
   WHERE (locale = 'a' and key in ('foo')) OR ...
   ```

   This would be a better approach if I cannot avoid the OR statements. I can analyse the requests further and find patterns, e.g. usually, a request would repeat the same locales.
3. Is it better to just filter on keys (omit locales from the query) and filter on the app layer, meaning more data returned from the datastore? e.g.

   ```sql
   WHERE key in ('foo', 'bar')
   ```

---

Edit 1:

I did an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as requested by @jjanes. The results are encouraging. I had to trim the output since it didn't fit here.

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on translation  (cost=2162.38..2572.98 rows=129 width=91) (actual time=1.840..2.018 rows=500 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: >>...(repeated my query)<<
  Heap Blocks: exact=28
  Buffers: shared hit=1028
  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=2162.38..2162.38 rows=131 width=0) (actual time=1.827..1.922 rows=0 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1000
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on unique_translation  (cost=0.00..4.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((key = 'd4f325a3-81ed-4bcc-a387-1dbb34f17896'::text) AND ((locale)::text = 'es-CL'::text))
              Buffers: shared hit=2
        >>... 499 more of the above<<

Planning Time: 3.229 ms
Execution Time: 6.752 ms
```

Comment: What is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`?

Comment: Keys can be maximum 500, the locales set is about 50

Comment: @jjanes, see "Edit 1" above for EXPLAIN results. Also, thanks for mentioning BUFFERS, it's a really interesting metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is probably to avoid `OR` altogether, as in

```
SELECT *
FROM translation
WHERE (key, locale) IN
   (('foo', 'a'), ('foo', 'b'), ('foo', 'c'),
    ('bar', 'c'), ('bar', 'd'), ('bar', 'e'));
```

If the condition is comparatively selective, that could use an index scan on the index behind the unique constraint. If not, it may perform a sequential scan, but the performance won't be worse than with your query.

Comment: Does this really help?  Isn't that `IN` a 6-way `OR`?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, but the PostgreSQL optimizer doesn't figure that all the branches of the `OR` compare with the same column using `=`. So it can at best come up with a bunch of index scans and a "bitmap or", as opposed to a single index scan, which is possible with my suggestion. Both versions can be fast enough, but mine will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a query like that is forcing a full index scan, or worse a full table scan, then often multiple queries `UNION`ed can perform better:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM translation
 WHERE key = 'foo' 
   AND locale in ('a', 'b', 'c')

 UNION ALL

SELECT *
  FROM translation
 WHERE key = 'bar' 
   AND locale in ('c', 'd', 'e')

     ;
```

This way you will usually get a much more efficient plan for each of the `SELECT`s, in this case a simple index seek on `(key, locale)` followed by a lookup for the other values `*` needs to return, and then combining all the data from each match is relatively quick.

This works particularly well when each of the resultset is expected to return a small number of rows.

It has the disadvantage of being more verbose if the query is more complicated as you have to repeat much of it multiple times in each `SELECT`. This can be cercumvented by making the main query `FROM`/`JOIN`s into a CTE and querying the rest from that:

```sql
WITH Ctranslation AS (
     SELECT * 
       FROM translation   AS t
       JOIN somethingelse AS s ON s.someId = t.someId
       JOIN anotherthing  AS a ON a.someId = s.someId
)

SELECT *
  FROM Ctranslation
 WHERE key = 'foo' 
   AND locale in ('a', 'b', 'c')

 UNION ALL

SELECT *
  FROM Ctranslation
 WHERE key = 'bar' 
   AND locale in ('c', 'd', 'e')

     ;
```

<sup>NOTE1: That CTE syntax is SQL Server, my main database haunting ground, you *may* have to alter it for postgres.</sup>

<sup>NOTE2: Take care with CTEs if you need to support old installations of postgres, until a couple of versions ago they were an optimisation fence that blocked predicate pushdown and may make the situation much less optimal. In that case you'd need to stick with the more long-winded version.</sup>

---

For a simple query like this, where the same compound index can be used for all the conditions, Laurenz's answer will be more efficient. The union method is more generally applicable and will work in DBs where using `IN` on multiple columns is not supported.